# What happens when there's a mismatch of vertex attribute sizes

Tags: c++, opengl

If I had two buffers which are bound to a program, but the size of one buffer is smaller than the other. When the vertex shader executes will extra values be generated until the largest buffer is finished or will the vertex shader stop execution when the smaller buffer is depleted. Assmue that there's less normals than verticies.

```
glGenBuffers(1, &array_1_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, array_1_id);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticies->size(), verticies->data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);
setVertexAttribute(program_id, "verticies", size, type, normalized, stride, offset);

glGenBuffers(1, &array_2_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, array_2_id);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals->size(), normals->data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);
setVertexAttribute(program_id, "normals", size, type, normalized, stride, offset);
```

The code is to show what I mean, so variables are pseudo.

Comment: you should probably multiply `normals->size()` with `sizeof(normals.at(0))`

Comment: It's pseudo code and the snippet this came from returns the size in bytes, but with a std::vector, definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't read more than the minimum of the two then there is no problem.

Otherwise in older versions it's undefined behavior (of the nazal demon type) to try and draw more than `normals->size()` vertices.

However if the extension `ARB_robustness` or `KHR_robustness` is enabled then the values passed to the shaders will be undefined but won't cause undefined behavior (behavior in the shader notwithstanding).